# Passing an array to a collection

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to pass an array to a collection, but I cannot seem to get the collection to populate.

```
Public Function CreateCol(ws As Worksheet, ary, col As collection)
Dim rng As Range, collect As collection
Dim y, skey, svalue

    On Error Resume Next
    'populate fund list

    For y = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
        If ary(y) <> "" Then
            skey = Trim(ary(y))
            svalue = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ws.Range("A:A"), ary(y), ws.Range("P:P"))
            collect.Add svalue, skey
        End If
    Next y


End Function
```

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. `collect.Add` is throwing run-time error 91 because you never `Set` it to a valid object reference.

Comment: Are you passing it the collection you want populated or are you returning the collection?

Answer (score 0):

As Mat's Mug said, make sure to set the collection to an object reference.  One way to do this is to put `set collect = new collection` before your for loop.